# Delphi: make function which returns PopupMenu result

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Usual case for Delphi menus is: call TPopupMenu.Popup, assign OnClick handler before, and now OnClick handler "returns" result: clicked menu index. I need to show popupmenu in other way: I want to show N items in menu, and get clicked index (0 to N-1) without making OnClick. How to do it?

I want to make `function DoMenu(List: TStringList): Integer` which returns index of clicked menu item (items are from `List`).

Comment: This seems odd. Delphi menu objects present an event driven model. You want a synchronous model. Use the raw Windows API for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TPopupMenu.Popup()` does not give you that info.  You will have to call the Win32 [`TrackPopupMenu()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function directly, specifying the `TPM_RETURNCMD` flag.  That will give you the *ID* of the item clicked, not the *index*, but you can manually determine the index using the ID if needed.

Or, you could simply assign a private `OnClick` event handler to each menu item, and use the `TPopupMenu.Tag` property (or other means) of passing around a pointer to an `Integer` that the `OnClick` handler can assign the index to, and then return that `Integer` value after `Popup()` exits. It is really not that hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I made such func.

```
function DoShowPopupMenu(List: TTntStringList; Pnt: TPoint; hWnd: THandle): Integer;
var
  hMenu: THandle;
  n: integer;
begin
  hMenu:= CreatePopupMenu;
  for n:= 0 to List.Count-1 do
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_ENABLED or MF_STRING or MF_UNCHECKED, 100+n, PWChar(List[n]));

  n:= Integer(TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN or TPM_LEFTBUTTON or TPM_RETURNCMD,
Pnt.X, Pnt.Y, 0, hWnd, nil));
  SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);

  if n>0 then
Result:= n-100
  else
Result:= -1;

  for n:= List.Count-1 downto 0 do
DeleteMenu(hMenu, n, MF_BYCOMMAND);
  DestroyMenu(hMenu);
end;
```

Comment: `TTntStringList` is Unicode stringlist for Delphi7. Use `TStringList` for new IDE